# serilog: CorrelationId without output template

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I am trying to add 'CorrelationId' without using `outputTemplate` for Serilog.

If I am using below code then none of log I have any 'CorrelationId'

```
  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .Enrich.WithCorrelationId()
            .CreateLogger();

14:34:23 INF] Response: HTTP GET /test responded 200 in 61.6772 ms
```

If I am using `.WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")` then ONLY CorrelationId added in logs.

Question, Is this necessary to use `outputTemplate`, can I achieve without it?

Comment: Where do you want the correlation id to be shown?

Comment: In log output... 14:34:23 INF] Response: HTTP GET /test responded 200 in 61.6772 ms